# Yii2 Check if phone number begins with 234

Tags: php, yii2

Please using Rules in YII2 how do I validate that a phone number begins with 234.

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        [['phone'], 'int'],
        [['firstname', 'lastname','phone', 'required'],
        [['phone'], 'int', 'max' => 13],
    ];
}
```

Comment: You need regex [yii2 validation match regular expression pattern got invalid input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43220784/yii2-validation-match-regular-expression-pattern-got-invalid-input)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the right code:

public function rules() {

```
return [
    [['phone'], 'int'],
    [['firstname', 'lastname','phone', 'required'],
    [['phone'], 'int', 'max' => 13],
    ['phone', 'match', 'pattern' => '^234']
];
```

}

Comment: Please use [['phone'], 'number'],

Answer (score 2):

Use pattern for this as below code:

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        [['phone'], 'int'],
        [['firstname', 'lastname','phone', 'required'],
        [['phone'], 'int', 'max' => 13],
        ['phone', 'match', 'pattern' => '^234']
    ];
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: thanks for your response but what your code does is to check if whats type is exactly 234 what i want to do is check if it starts or begins with 234. Do you copy?

Comment: Do you mean that phone number should start with either 2 or 3 or 4 ? or phone number will always have 234 as its first 3 character?

Comment: Here is the right code:

public function rules() {
    return [
        [['phone'], 'int'],
        [['firstname', 'lastname','phone', 'required'],
        [['phone'], 'int', 'max' => 13],
        ['phone', 'match', 'pattern' => '^234']
    ];
}

Comment: cool, I haven't tested that code. Happy you are done with this :)